# Hyperlink Doesn't go to correct Link when page is protected

Tags: excel

I have a worksheet that has 8 hyperlinks placed in different cells that are linked to 8 different worksheets. These links work perfectly whilst the page is unlocked. However, when I try to protect the sheet so only the hyperlinks are active (by leaving the insert hyperlink ticked) then the page is locked and all the hyperlinks are active as it should be. The problem is that the first hyperlink you click goes to the correct page, but if I go back the main worksheet and click on a different hyperlink it goes to the same page as the first time it was used. It doesn't matter which hyperlink I try, they all revert to the first successful connection. If I un-protect the sheet, the hyperlinks then work fine again!! I cannot seem to figure out what is going on. Do I need to use some VBA code to reset the main worksheet every time I go back into it? Or is there some other simple explanation that I cannot seem to find elsewhere online?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out how to get the hyperlinks to work correctly when the page is locked down. If you have created a hyperlink in a cell to any other cell or page, when you protect the sheet the hyperlink stops working correctly (and just goes to the last page you accessed. The hyperlink also works anywhere on the page & not just in the cell where it was originally placed). To get the hyperlink to work correctly once you protect the page requires you to place a hyperlink button over the cell instead (go to insert, photo) once you have created the photo, resize it to fit over the cell you want to act as a hyperlink - you can then edit it to make it 100% transparent so it doesn't show on the page, but it still works. Finally link the hidden picture to your destination point.